# I'm trying to install psycopg2 onto Mac OS 10.6.3; it claims it can't find "stdarg.h" but I can see it's there; what should I do?

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, psycopg2

I'm desperately trying to successfully install psycopg2 but keep running into errors. The latest one seems to involve it not being to find "stdarg.h" (see code below). However I can see with my own eyes that a file called stdarg.h exists at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h (where it claims it can't find anything) so I've no idea what to do about it.

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.3 and within the last few days I've made sure I have all the latest OS developer tools.

I have Python 2.6.2 and PostgreSQL 8.4 if that makes any difference.

```
python setup.py install    
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/psycopg
gcc -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.2.1 (dt dec ext pq3)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080404 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DHAVE_PQPROTOCOL3=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -I. -I/opt/local/include/postgresql84 -I/opt/local/include/postgresql84/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:4,
             from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
             from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:4,
             from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
             from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/MQ/MQ-tWOWWG+izzuZCrAJpzk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccakFhRS.out
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your specific problem but i recommend you to install it using [macports](http://www.macports.com).
Installing [psycopg2](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=psycopg2) is as simply as:

```
sudo port install py26-psycopg2
```

Comment: @cojadate it depends on what version of Python you are currently using. If you are running with python2.6 , py26-psycopg2 is the right choice. psycopg2 is surely installed but i guess is not in your Python path.

Comment: @cojadate If you installed psycopg2 using MacPorts, you need to make sure that you're using the ports version of Python instead of the one that ships with OSX. Make sure `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/` or similar is in your `PATH` before `/usr/bin` or what-have-you.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

1. `$ mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute psycopg2_test`
2. `$ cd $VIRTUAL_ENV`
3. `$ pip install psycopg2`

#### Notes

- I installed my base Python via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).
- The above commands make use of:

  - [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)
  - [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper)
  - [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
- I bootstrapped `pip` via the following:

  1. `wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py`
  2. `python distribute_setup.py`
  3. `easy_install pip`

UPDATE: I realize it seems like a lot of yak shaving, but learning how to use `virtualenv` and friends is an up-front investment that pays off pretty quickly, especially when dealing with projects that have a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a very similar problem as this (except with OSX Lion, Python 2.7) [Can't install psycopg2 in virtualenv "error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327503/cant-install-psycopg2-in-virtualenv-error-stdarg-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

I ended up using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8834568/396327

Basically, uninstalling/reinstalling XCode from scratch (and a few more hacks to get it to recognize gcc-4.2).