# Changing pg_config

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing a very similar problem as [I'm trying to install psycopg2 onto Mac OS 10.6.3; it claims it can't find "stdarg.h" but I can see it's there; what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044801/im-trying-to-install-psycopg2-onto-mac-os-10-6-3-it-claims-it-cant-find-stda) (except I'm on OS X 10.7 and PostgreSQL v 9.0.5), and I'm thinking about changing my psql config c-compiler.

When I type pg_config in terminal I get:

```
BINDIR = /usr/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/share/doc/postgresql
HTMLDIR = /Library/WebServer/Documents/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/include/postgresql/server
LIBDIR = /usr/lib
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql
LOCALEDIR = /usr/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/share/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/share/postgresql
SYSCONFDIR = /private/etc/postgresql
PGXS = /usr/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--sbindir=/usr/libexec' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--localstatedir=/var/pgsql' '--htmldir=/Library/WebServer/Documents/postgresql' '--enable-thread-safety' '--enable-dtrace' '--with-tcl' '--with-perl' '--with-python' '--with-gssapi' '--with-krb5' '--with-pam' '--with-ldap' '--with-bonjour' '--with-openssl' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo' 'CFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Os -g -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations' 'LDFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Os -g -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations' 'LDFLAGS_EX=-mdynamic-no-pic'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/libxml2
CFLAGS = -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Os -g -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
CFLAGS_SL = 
LDFLAGS = -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Os -g -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs
LDFLAGS_EX = -mdynamic-no-pic
LDFLAGS_SL = 
LIBS = -lpgport -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -lreadline -lm 
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.0.5
```

I'm wondering how to change pg_config (so I can set CC = gcc-4.2) or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pg_config](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-pgconfig.html) is just a util that provides information, it is not a "config" in the typical sense that you can edit properties.  If you want to change a value that `pg_config` provides, you will need to manually do so outside of the util (in your case, you will need to install a new C compiler).

Comment: Confirming this, in those notes, you find the `--configure` parameter which is not a way to configure the given pg_config, but which can only be used at build time: `--configure: Print the options that were given to the configure script when PostgreSQL was configured for building. This can be used to reproduce the identical configuration, or to find out with what options a binary package was built. (Note however that binary packages often contain vendor-specific custom patches.)`